# jQuery tab and tab content show up when clicked ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My webpage is at http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/resume

All the HTML, CSS and jQuery code + images are available there for anyone to access.

My issue is that currently my jQuery code makes the tabs show the tab-content when I click on the achor tag of the tab. But the tab doesnt change into the clicked tab.(tab name remains the same).

And the tab changes into the clicked tab when i click on the respective li of the tab. What I want is that both the tab changes and the content of the tab shows when I click on the either the li of the tab or the anchor of the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two lots of events registered. One on the anchors and the other on the lis. The one on the lis changes the active state for the tabs themselves while the one on the anchors change the content. You should combine these into one function.

You change check the li function is working by clicking on the very bottom edge of it. Because your anchor javascript has a `return false` feclaration it is preventing the click event bubbling up to the li, thus not showing the change.

Comment: can you tell me how to combine the two please. I am a very beginner at jQuery. thanks

Comment: Just saw this request - I think that user981097 has provided a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666654/jquery-tab-and-tab-content-show-up-when-clicked/7666916#7666916 . I suspect you will have some redundant code remaining but the effect should function correctly

Comment: nope. same as before(jeff's code). the respective content doesnt show up with the li element.

Comment: does that happen when you click the text itself? If so it's because your anchor is quite small - add `display:block` to the `<a />` in your CSS and it will fill the available space. I can get it to work on chrome by modifying the javascript and CSS on the page you provided

Comment: no, it happens when I click on the white space around the text(the li tag) containing the anchor. I want the respective content to show up for that too. Thanks alot!

Comment: Right so if it works when you click the text then add the CSS as in my comment above and it should then work if you click the text OR the white space

Comment: Oh, Silly Me ! Thanks alot for taking the time. Really appreciate it ! :)

Comment: No problems - glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the function:

```
 $("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li > a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#wrap > div").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(activeTab).show();
        return false;
    });
```

to the following:

```
 $("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#wrap > div").hide();
        $(".active-tab").removeClass();
        $(this).parent().addClass("active-tab");
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(activeTab).show();
        return false;
    });
```

This should work and you should be able to remove your other javascript function.

Comment: this is great..thanks. Just one thing, when the page first loads it does show all of the content(the content of the other tabs too) in the first tab. I only want the content of the first tab to be shown there. So on page load, the first tab should be activated by default. How do i do that?

Comment: Did you remove the other lines in the ready function? You're going to want those and I would expect them still to work. Is that not the case?

Comment: okay this works. I have to keep all previous javascript functions to make it work. Just one thing, want the respective content to show as the tab changes when clicked on the li also(the white space around the anchor). Currently, when clicked there, the tab changes, but the respective content does not show up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already use jQuery you can use the jQueryUI library to create tabs. It is very simple and the style can easily be changed. Here is the Tutorial for tabs:

[jQuery UI - Tabs Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

If you click the whitespace around the text in the tabs, it works.  Remove the anchor link from inside the tab, or add a click handler for the anchor link.


**Edit:**

My mistake.  You have a click handler on your `anchor` element, but clicking the `anchor` link causes it to become `$(this)` in your code.  So you assign `class="active"` to the `anchor`, when you want to assign it to the `li`.

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

should be rewritten to modify the `li`.  Personally, I would wrap the `li` in the anchor link:

```
<a href="#something"><li></li></a>
```

This will probably require modifying your JS code a little, but will give a uniform result.

Comment: how do i add a click handler for the anchor link? Can you please explain a little... I am a JavaScript beginner. Thanks! :)

Comment: you definitely don't want to wrap an `<li />` in an `<a />` - it's invalid code and could be parsed differently by different browsers.